Should [pools] and [mining-pools] be synonyms?
The tags are basically the same anyway.

Yeah, seems like an obvious merge. And someone's done it already. :)

Then where would questions about swimming pools, tidal pools, games of pool, and people with the last name 'Pool' go?

To the forum, as they are off-topic?;)

Ok, it looks like Dori♦ has already started the process to deal with these synonyms.
